# Database mapping

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have created a MySql database with two tables (books, members). A member can have many books and a certain book can have only one member. I want to create a spring boot project that will be a REST API that preforms CRUD operations on a database. For database operations I'm using Spring Data JPA.

[image]

Next I have created two classes called books and members.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "members")
    public class Members {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "last_name")
        private String lastName;

        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String firstName;

        @Column(name = "address")
        private String address;

        @Column(name = "phone_num")
        private String phoneNum;

        @Column(name = "email")
        private String email;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "members", cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
        private List<Books> books;

//getters and setters

@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Books {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "author_last_name")
    private String authorLastName;

    @Column(name = "author_first_name")
    private String authorFirstName;

    @Column(name = "publisher")
    private String publisher;

    @Column(name = "publishing_year")
    private String publishingYear;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_member")
    private Members members;
//getters and setters
```

I have created an interface called LibraryRepository that extends JpaRepository.

```
    public interface LibraryRepository extends JpaRepository<Members, Integer> {
    }
```

My LibraryService interface

```
public interface LibraryService {
    List<Members> findAll();
}
```

and LibraryServiceImpl classes

```
@Service
public class LibraryServiceImpl implements LibraryService {

    private LibraryRepository libraryRepository;

    @Autowired
    public LibraryServiceImpl(LibraryRepository libraryRepository) {
        this.libraryRepository = libraryRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Members> findAll() {
        return libraryRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

And rest controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class LibraryRestController {

    private LibraryService libraryService;

    @Autowired
    public LibraryRestController(LibraryService libraryService) {
        this.libraryService = libraryService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/loans")
    public List<Members> findAll(){
        return libraryService.findAll();
    }
}
```

One of the members has one book on loan.
When I run the application and use a GET method on `http://localhost:8080/api/loans` what is returned is an infinite list. A member has a book and this book has a member, and this member has a book and so on.....

I believe that something is wrongly mapped on my entity classes but I can't find what exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a bi-directional mapping between Member and Book. This is a circular dependency and if the JSON marshaller (Jackson) is converting the objects to JSON it follows the dependencies and produces an infinite loop.

You have to use JSON annotations to break this loop.

For example:

```
@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "members", cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
private List<Books> books;
```

and

```
@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "id_member")
private Members members;
```

This is just an example and it's up to you to decide which of the dependency is the managed reference.

Read more about that topic here:
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion